# When linked from Instagram website layout breaks

Tags: html, css, svg

So I was just testing phone functionality for my site. It operates as expected (ie the logo is at the top), but when clicked through as a link from instagram it displays as below. Is it something to do with the bar that is displayed in the link from instagram?

[image: As it should appear]

[image: When linked from Instagram]

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzwm6zwf/)

html

```
     <div class="Rad_title_container">
        <div class="Rad_title">
        <svg>
</svg> 
        </div>
        </div>
```

css

```
.Rad_title_container{
  width:100%;
}

.Rad_title {
  padding-top:2%;
  padding-left:17.5%;
  z-index:3;
  position:fixed;
  width:65%;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems it didn't like position:fixed. I had to add a max height as well because it was doing something funky like expanding the height to 200%. No idea what was going on.

```
.Rad_title_container{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    z-index:3;
  }

.Rad_title {
  padding-top:2%;
   position:relative;
   width:65%;
   pointer-events:none;
   text-align:center;
   margin:auto;
   max-height:10vh;
   overflow-y:none;
}
```